# How to verify if a date exists between certain periods (excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following tables:

```
Zone Starting Period Ending Period (of inavailabilty)
Z1   20.10.2013      25.10.2013
Z1   21.11.2013      23.11.2013
```

---

```
Date       Zone  Its ok 
15.02.2013 Z1    Ok.
```

I want to calculate if the date from second table interfeer with the periods from the first table to show me a message, and if not to say Ok.

Can it be done?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$3=K9)*(J9>$B$2:$B$3)*(J9<$C$2:$C$3))=0,"OK","Not OK")
```

where

- `$A$2:$A$3` is Zone from table 1
- `$B$2:$B$3` is Starting Period from table 1
- `$C$2:$C$3` is Ending Period from table
- `K9` is Zone from table 2
- `J9` is Date from table 2

Comment: but i must verify first if the date is for Z1 or not

Comment: idk why but says ok all the time no matter what date i put in. do you have any ideea why ?